# Facebook iOS SDK returns error "com.facebook.sdk error 4"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Today we started to get the following error when using the Facebook SDK for iOS to try and query some pages streams:

Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 4.)" UserInfo=0xb8606d0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=

This code used to work for months. Anyone knows what error code 4 means???

Comment: This code even happened on my original iOS Facebook App. I'm still thinking about how did I made 1M request by using it normally though :)

Answer (score 1):

See this page on how to properly handle errors:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/

Code 4 looks like you're being throttled because you're making too many requests.